# Can we edit custom metadata types after deploying to production?

Tags: change-set, custom-metadata

I am new to salesforce development, Suppose I have a custom metadata type custom__mdt, and it has two fields, Custom_Field_one__c and Custom_Field_two__c. Let's say the field values are null while deploying the custom metadata type. My question is after deployment, Can I edit the field values?

Comment: Yes, you can edit in Setup just like with any other custom metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but if you have some CI/CD in place, then this will get overridden by the data you have in your VCS.

If you (or anyone else, or a CI/CD system like the above) uses the metadata API or a changeset to re-deploy the custom metadata record, changes you made in production will be overwritten.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Custom metadata are just a regular custom object, you can create, edit, delete them. The beauty of them is that you can deploy them as well. SO depends on if you use any CI/CD like Travis or Gearset to deploy to your production from VCS. If so you need to update the custom metadata in the VCS as well in order to not override them.